# Syncronize time wint NTP-servers without admin rights

Tags: c#, ntp, systemtime

I wrote an application, that grab time from NTP server and change system time of my machine. It works good, but time synchronizing only if my apps start with admin rights. So a question is how to launch it without admin privileges, but to save it functionality?
I set system time using WinAPI function `SetSystemTime`.

Comment: The function itself documents this: you need an account capable of getting the `SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME` privilege. Without admin rights, that means the account the app runs under must have been granted the "change the system time" right through Local Security Policy (or with `secedit` if you don't want to use the GUI).

Comment: I launch my app from my account after granting me a privilege to change system time, but without admin rights app don't work

Comment: Then you're probably doing something wrong. I know this setup works because existing tools that sync time (e.g. [this one](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/sw/ntp.htm)) work just fine without admin rights after being granted this right. (Incidentally, using an existing tool for syncing time is probably a better idea than rolling your own -- see also `w32tm`.)

Comment: If you're launching your app under an account that's a member of Administrators, but without elevation, I imagine the split token approach of UAC may also strip the account of any special privileges it has been granted separately, aside from not making it an admin. If that's the case then you need to either elevate, or use an account that's not an admin.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, is this info actual for windows Server 2012 or Windows 10?

Comment: As far as I know, everything I've said applies to all versions of Windows from XP onwards (except that I don't know how UAC and the system time privilege interact, that's speculation). W7 introduced a new API for getting better time, that's about it. In my company we're still using vanilla ntpd compiled for Win32 as a service to sync time (because the built-in services aren't good enough), with the Meinberg installer.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, your last suggestion was clearly right. After using non admin account my app work as expected. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in several ways (have the most proper one for you).

1. Identity Impersonation => described with example [at this address](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2005/03/22/safely-impersonating-another-user/)

   `WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(accessToken);
    WindowsImpersonationContext context = identity.Impersonate() ;`
2. runas verb

   `ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo (m_strInstallUtil, strExePath);
   startInfo.Verb = "runas";
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (startInfo);`

please keep in mind that UAC will be prompted for the second method

3. PrincipalPermissin (if the user is the member of Admin group)

   `[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = @"BUILTIN\Administrators")]`